# .submit( handler ) Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit

I can't seem to get jquery .submit method to execute. I have a feeling its a silly mistake but I've been stuck for hours. Any idea whats wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform" action="sendEmail.php">
    <div class="form-group" action="" method="post">
        <label for="Email" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="Message" placeholder="Message" required/></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="pillButton" ><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
alert("outside submit function"); // Works
$("#contactform").submit(function(event) { // Event not working
  event.preventDefault();  
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
});
```

Comment: Wrap in a `$(function() {...});` ? jQuery actually loaded? Any console messages?

Comment: the code is ok you have to have another bug somewhere else

Comment: mplungjan you solved my problem.. I had to wrapper with a ready listner! Thanks ^.^  ... post an answer so that I can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely what you are missing - a load wrapper:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gvex5wo8/)

```
$(function () {
    alert("outside submit function"); // Works
    $("#contactform").submit(function (event) { // Event now working
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
    });
});
```